# rsyslog doesnt seem to write to log file, without restart after touch'ing the file

Tags: rsyslog

I have a separate file for logging `local7` facility, and this file is `touch`ed and
*permissions* set, from my installer. But sometimes I see that the logs are not being written to it (after I do a re-install) until I do `rsyslog restart`!

Is it mandatory to *restart* `rsyslog` if the log file is `touch`ed by another program/application ?

(since the installer is run as `root`, the 
log file's time-stamp will be changed due to `touch` - will this cause `rsyslog` to not write to the log file ?)

Answer (score 0):

rsyslogd has each log file open continuously for writing and it doesn't know that you've yanked the file out from under it. The file your installer removed is still on disk in an unlinked state and is still being written to. You can tell rsyslogd to reopen all log files by `killall -HUP rsyslogd` instead of doing a full restart.

Comment: my installer is not _removing_ the file, its just doing a `touch` + `chmod` - for this too, do I need a `kill -HUP` ?

Comment: @vyom Your installer is creating a new file via touch according to your post. If you create a new file you will need to send a HUP to rsyslogd or restart it. If you are just changing a timestamp or permissions then you do not need to do anything.

Comment: ok, I meant `touch`, I have edited the question, to keep it simple, the installer always does a `touch <file>` and then `chmod` on it. So, from your explanation I dont need a `HUP`, but somehow I see this issue that after an installation the logging not happening until I restart `rsyslog` !

Comment: If `rsyslog` has a lock on the file, then your script can not write to it (including `touch` and `chmod` functions) until the lock is released.  You have to (briefly) end that lock on the file, perform your touch and chmod changes, and then resume rsyslog (which, then again, creates a continuous lock on that file). Got it?

Answer (score 0):

For obvious reasons, rsyslog is a rigidly designed program that follows its configuration. It's unambiguous. If it was possible to do what you want to do, it would make a giant security hole.